# HTTP server in Java using HTTPServer Class

Tags: java, httpserver

I have to create a HTTP web server (file based) in Java using the HttpServer and HttpHandler classes. I cannot find suitable samples and tutorials Also, I would like to know the basics I should know before coding up a server , eg. keep-alive, thread-pooling etc.
Where can I find such tutorials?

Comment: googling "java httpserver tutorial" returns plenty of results.  Are these results unacceptable for some reason?

Comment: Most of them use "ServerSocket" and "Socket" class. I need to create via "HttpServer" class. Resources are fairly limited for that. I mean I can't find some satisfactory ones. I would really appreciate if you could suggest a book.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use Jetty as your server? It is lightweight and easy to use and configure.

Comment: I understand I can use other servers but actually I have to develop a web server itself. Sort of a self learning project for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are docs with examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

BUT:
It is really bad idea using com.sun.* stuff such as Httphandler and HttpServer. Avoid this. Try using raw sockets or some other third party libs. (For example netty). Also, there are lots of SingleClassHttpServerInJava examples over internet.

Comment: why is it bad to use that?